# struct object same name as data name

Tags: objective-c

I have come across code like this :

```
struct abc
{
    //some code
};

//some lines of code

struct abc *abc;
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is there an advantage to this usage?
2. Does the compiler interpret it differently from:

   ```
   struct abc *diffname;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about giving a variable a name similar to its type name.  For native types, it's impossible, since the type names are all reserved.  For your case of structures, however,

```
struct abc *abc;
```

and

```
struct abc *diffname;
```

are exactly the same, except that they have different names.  I don't see any particular "advantage" to using the `abc`.